# iOS swift 4 sort dictionary by a particular values

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, dictionary

Can you please help me sorting the dictionary below with value "Val1".

```
var data = ["key1" : ["val1": 1,"val2": 1],
            "key2" : ["val1": 5,"val2": 2],
            "key3" : ["val1": 0,"val2": 9]]
```

I am expecting this dictionary to be sorted like this. Highest values of 'Val1' to be on top (descending order)..

```
var data = [ "key2" : ["val1": 5,"val2": 2],
             "key1" : ["val1": 1,"val2": 1],
             "key3" : ["val1": 0,"val2": 9]]
```

Comment: Dictionaries have no concept of ordering and cannot be sorted. To sort something you need a list (array). You can get the keys and sort them by their values. Anyway, you should start by converting the dictionary to an object with properties first.

Comment: Thanks Paulo. I would try the recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sulthan correctly pointed out `Dictionary` cannot be sorted. If you still want to, you'll get an `Array` as result.

```
let data = [
    "key1": ["val1": 1,"val2": 1],
    "key2": ["val1": 5,"val2": 2],
    "key3": ["val1": 0,"val2": 9]
]

let result = data.sorted { $0.1["val1"]! > $1.1["val1"]! }
print(result)
```

> [(key: "key2", value: ["val1": 5, "val2": 2]), 
>   (key: "key1", value: ["val1": 1, "val2": 1]), 
>   (key: "key3", value: ["val1": 0, "val2": 9])]

Comment: Thanks.. is it possible to convert the 'result' back to the same dictionary structure ( data1 = [String: [ Stirng : String ]]  ) ?

Comment: @AnbarasuP if we try to convert it back to dictionary structure, the ordering would be lost

Comment: Oh.. Thanks a lot.. Good learning. I model the data in different way