# Swift sort dictionary by value as Array

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, uicollectionview

Hello guys i have struct **Datas()** which contains field **start** with date. I have like 24 objects and i want to add it to collection and sort collection by time (**.start** field). I tried answers from stack, but it not my case.

```
var todaysTimes = [Int:[Datas]]()


struct Datas {

var id: Int
var isVisited: Bool
var start: Date
var end: Date
}
```

**configure cell**

```
private func configureCell(collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let availableSessionTimeCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: availableSessionCell, for: indexPath) as! EVAvailableSessionTimeCell
    let dataItem = todaysTimes[clinicSection[indexPath.section]!]![indexPath.row]

   availableSessionTimeCell.dateLabel.text = Date.time(day: dataItem.start)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS swift 4 sort dictionary by a particular values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54732911/ios-swift-4-sort-dictionary-by-a-particular-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood you would like to **sort the array of object Datas** in your dictionary. But not sort the `dictionary` itself. In case you would like to sort every `value` (which is `[Datas]`) in your dictionary `key-value` then in your `viewDidLoad()` probably you could sort the array in your data to be as you wished (either `ascending` or `descending`).

You can achieve it by looping in your dictionary and sort the values in a way like this:

```
for (id, datas) in todaysTimes {
        todaysTimes[id] = datas.sorted(by: { $0.start.compare($1.start) == .orderedDescending })
    }
```

For a complete **example**, you can try this in http://online.swiftplayground.run/:

```
struct Datas {
    var id: Int
    var isVisited: Bool
    var start: Date
    var end: Date
}

// Dump data to show an example
var todaysTimes = [Int:[Datas]]()
let today = Date()
let one_day_before_today = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: today)!
let two_day_before_today = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -2, to: today)!
todaysTimes[1] = [Datas(id: 1, isVisited: false, start: one_day_before_today, end: Date()), Datas(id: 1, isVisited: false, start: today, end: Date()), Datas(id: 1, isVisited: false, start: two_day_before_today, end: Date())]

// Sort Descending
print("Sorted descending")
for (id, datas) in todaysTimes {
    todaysTimes[id] = datas.sorted(by: { $0.start.compare($1.start) == .orderedDescending })
}
print(todaysTimes)

// Sort Ascending
print("Sorted ascending")
for (id, datas) in todaysTimes {
    todaysTimes[id] = datas.sorted(by: { $0.start.compare($1.start) == .orderedAscending })
}
print(todaysTimes)

// Will print these two lines
// Sorted descending
// [1: [SwiftPlayground.Datas(id: 1, isVisited: false, start: 2019-06-21 12:13:34 +0000, end: 2019-06-21 12:13:34 +0000), SwiftPlayground.Datas(id: 1, isVisited: false, start: 2019-06-20 12:13:34 +0000, end: 2019-06-21 12:13:34 +0000), SwiftPlayground.Datas(id: 1, isVisited: false, start: 2019-06-19 12:13:34 +0000, end: 2019-06-21 12:13:34 +0000)]]
// Sorted ascending
// [1: [SwiftPlayground.Datas(id: 1, isVisited: false, start: 2019-06-19 12:13:34 +0000, end: 2019-06-21 12:13:34 +0000), SwiftPlayground.Datas(id: 1, isVisited: false, start: 2019-06-20 12:13:34 +0000, end: 2019-06-21 12:13:34 +0000), SwiftPlayground.Datas(id: 1, isVisited: false, start: 2019-06-21 12:13:34 +0000, end: 2019-06-21 12:13:34 +0000)]]
// Try the example in online.swiftplayground.run
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to sort your array before calling configureCell. So in your viewDidLoad method you should use something like this.

```swift
dates.sort(by: {(p1: Datas, p2: Datas) -> Bool in
        return p1.start > p2.start
    })
```

After this you are good to go.

Unfortunately sorting a dictionary is harder to achieve.

It is discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54732911/ios-swift-4-sort-dictionary-by-a-particular-values).

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to use a combination of `forEach(_:)` and `sorted(_:)` to get that working, i.e.

```
var todaysTimes = [Int:[Datas]]()
todaysTimes.forEach { (key,value) in
    let newValue = value.sorted(by: { $0.start < $1.start }) //will sort in ascending order
    todaysTimes[key] = newValue
}
```

In case you want to sort it in *descending order*, you just using `>` instead of `<`, i.e.

```
let newValue = value.sorted(by: { $0.start > $1.start })
```